# Will the finally block be executed?

Tags: c#

I have read that `finally` block is always called after the `try catch` block.

I have a situation(please don't go syntactically)

**SITUATION 1:-**

```
try
{    
  return 1;
}
catch()
{
  return 2;
}
finally()
{
  Console.WriteLine("ABCD");
}
```

And another situation as:-

**SITUATION 2:-**

```
try
{
  System.Environment.Exit(1);
}
catch()
{
   return 2;
}
finally()
{
  Console.WriteLine("ABCD");
}
```

My question is that in both the situations will the `finally` block be executed if my code is entering in the try block?
If not please explain the reason.

My understanding is that `exit` is a system call and `return` is a function call.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the finally, run your own code, and find out.

Comment: `return` is not a function call.

Comment: Also, there is no concept of "system call" in C#. Where did you get this terminology?

Comment: `System.exit()` does not exist in C#.

Comment: I assume he meant `Environment.Exit`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and you cannot have return statements in a finally block.

Comment: The question should be closed, but not as a duplicate of that. Boo!

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of that question at all...

Comment: Why is everyone giving him a hard time? Everyone is complaining about little syntax errors instead of just answering the guys question.

Comment: @jb. Because until we know what is meant by `System.exit()`, the question cannot be answered. Now that it has been clarified, we can reopen.

Comment: @jb. Well, it's a pretty terrible question.  The OP clearly put virtually no effort into asking it at all.  He didn't bother to write compilable code, he didn't bother just running his code to get an answer (much simpler than asking here) which would tell him that his code doesn't compile, and give him a real answer as soon as he made it compile.  SO has a high standard for both questions and answers.  He doesn't have an inherent right to have us do his work for him.

Comment: Hello All, I am sorry if my question is not a very standard one. But I just wanted to know that will the finally block gets executed if I return from the try block. I have also updated my question.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Your edit cleaned it up a lot - I added an edit on my answer to address this, but the short answer is that both finally blocks would execute.

Comment: @jb: There are plenty of questions already devoted to whether or not a `finally` block executes. Additionally, the OP showed no effort to even check the specification which *very* clearly says: "The statements of a finally block are always executed when control leaves a try statement. This is true whether the control transfer occurs as a result of normal execution, as a result of executing a break, continue, goto, or return statement, or as a result of propagating an exception out of the try statement." Note that it very clearly says *when control leaves a try statement* and includes `return`.

Comment: @RahulTripathi And why didn't you just run the code yourself to get your answer instead of asking this question.  It would have saved you much more time.  Barring that, a pretty trivial google search or look through the documentation would answer the question, assuming you don't have access to a development environment.

Comment: @Jason: If there are plenty of such questions, why were they not linked here?

Comment: @jb: There *are* situations where control does *not* leave a try statement: e.g., `Environment.FailFast`, `OutOfMemoryException`, and the user just disconnecting the power source among others. But is abundantly clear from the manual for the programming language (i.e., the specification) that a `return` statement *will* cause the `finally` to execute. Why are people so reluctant to check the manual?

Comment: @Servy:- Sir I am really sorry but please remain calm. I have done my work. I have checked that finally is getting executed but what I wanted to know why is it that it is getting executed? As return should not allow it. I may be confused right now. But its a request be patient and calm. Sorry once again :(

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying any of these comments are invalid or wrong, all I'm saying is even with the syntax errors, it was pretty clear what the question was asking. It seems like instead of just heaping "you have an error!" comments on him, we could have just answered his question (as Reed did), or link him to one of the duplicate questions.

Comment: @RahulTripathi I am calm.  And no, you haven't done your work.  You didn't bother to compile your code.  You didn't bother to run it once you got to a comparable example.  You didn't bother to check the documentation regarding `finally` to see what it says on the subject.  You didn't look up any other sources of information regarding when a finally does and doesn't run.  You saying you did your work is obviously false.

Comment: @jb. Irregardless of the syntax errors, it's clear you put no effort at all into the question.  It is not *our* responsibility to put time and effort into your question because you just couldn't be bothered to even write a compilable example of something this simple.  SO doesn't exist to serve you.  We shouldn't have to be guessing what you meant by your code, you should take the time to write a question clear enough that we don't *have* to guess.  Next, regardless of whether it compiles or not, you still put *no* effort in trying to solve it.  That's a *much* bigger problem.

Comment: regarding your first scenario the finally will be executed allways even with the return,bear in mind the situation where you have a method that returns a dataset you normaly open connection,command,dataadapter,fill,return dataset,but what if something went wrong where do you provide the absolute safety that the connection will be close.....the finally block,even after you said in tryblock return dataset.

Answer (score 12):

<s>Neither example will compile, as a `return` statement is not allowed in a finally block.  This means that your first situation is not possible, and really doesn't need to be addressed.</s>

A return within the `try` will still cause the `finally` block to be executed, by design.

As for your second situation, in general, yes - your `finally` block will execute.  If you call [`Environment.FailFast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx), however, this method specifically:

> terminates a process without running any active try/finally blocks or finalizers.

In that case, the finally blocks would not occur.  Note that other methods which "exit" the process, such as [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) (or `Application.Shutdown` type calls) generally *will* execute the code within the `finally` block.

---

Given your edit, the first `finally` block will execute.

In the first case, the `return` within the `try` will trigger the `finally` block to execute.

In the second, `Environment.Exit` will exit the process immediately, and the finally will not execute.  Note that the catch block in situation 2 will *not* execute, as well, as [`Environment.Exit`'s documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) specifies:

> If Exit is called from a try or finally block, the code in any catch block does not execute. If the return statement is used, the code in the catch block does execute.

As for your last line:

> My understanding is that exit is a system call and return is a function call.

This is not really true.  `return` isn't a function call, it's a language specified [jump statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) for control flow.  `Environment.Exit` is actually a method call (the `Exit` method within the `Environment` class).

Comment: `Environment.Exit()` will terminate immediately and will not return. The finally block will not execute.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Look better?  Interestingly, the documentation doesn't suggest that (as it does in FailFast) - had to wire up a test.

Comment: Yes I think that's accurate now. As I say in my answer, it seems exceedingly likely that a call to `ExitProcess` is going to be made.

Answer (score 6):

**Situation 1**

The finally block will be executed. In normal scenarios, `finally` blocks are always executed.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zwc8s4fz.aspx) says, with my emphasis:

> Typically, the statements of a finally block run when control leaves a try statement. The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal execution, of execution of a break, continue, goto, or **return** statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

**Situation 2**

This is not a normal scenario. A call to `Environment.Exit()` terminates the process immediately, and the `finally` block is not executed.

The documentation does not make this clear. However, I'd be prepared to bet that inside the call to `Environment.Exit()` is a call to the Win32 API function `ExitProcess()`, and calls to that function never return.

Answer (score 4):

<s>`return` is not allowed in C# `finally` blocks. In fact, no flow-controlling command is allowed, except for `throw`. So no `return`, no `break`, no nothing.</s>

And if the `finally` block would not be executed at all, then it would not be called `finally` but `maybe`. `finally` blocks are guaranteed to be executed (unless your VM is running out of RAM, someone pulls the plug from your computer and so on), no matter if you are doing `return`, `throw` or anything else inside your `try` (or `catch`) block.

Comment: This really should be a comment.

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with the question, does it? Imagine any other statement in the `finally` block. Therefore, I strongly suggest this should be a comment.

Comment: Actually, it has a lot to do with the question. The question is which return statement is actually executed. And the one inside `finally` is not possible. If the one in the `finally` block were not a return statement, but any other statement, then of course it would get executed. But then, there would be no question which value is returned.

Comment: It's obvious what was meant and that the question was broken. Reed got it right, and this answer is pointless. I do suggest that you remove it.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus: The question is *which `finally` block* is going to be executed. It is completely irrelevant what is inside of that `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that finally block is always called after the try catch block.

This statement is *false*.  The `finally` block does *not* always execute.

Please check the language specification, 8.10:

> The statements of a `finally` block **are always executed when control leaves a `try` statement**. This is true whether the control transfer occurs as a result of normal execution, as a result of executing a `break`, `continue`, `goto`, or `return` statement, or as a result of propagating an exception out of the `try` statement.

Note that it says *when control leaves a `try` statement* and *includes* `return`. Note that there are cases where control does *not* leave a `try` statement: infinite loops, [`Environment.FailFast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx), `OutOfMemoryException`, the user disconnecting the power source, and other possibilities. These are the cases when `finally` will *not* execute.

In particular, in your first situation, the `finally` block *will* execute very simply because control leaves the `try` statement via a `return`, and per the specification, will execute.

Note that in your second situation, the `finally` block *will not* execute very simply because control does not leave the try block. Control is *terminated* immediately. The program stops running, there is no control to be transferred.

From the documentation for `Environment.Exit`:

> Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running. If the return statement is called in the application entry point, it causes an application to terminate only after all foreground threads have terminated.

Answer (score 0):

There is another interesting case regarding `Environment.Exit` that hasn't been discussed here. What if a *different* thread (to the one `Environment.Exit` is called from) is in the middle of a `try` clause? The docs don't say what happens, but according to my simple test the answer is still no - `finally` blocks are not executed:

```
var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Console.WriteLine("starting task...");
Task.Run(() =>
{
    try
    {
        mre.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("sleeping...");
        Thread.Sleep(9999);
        Console.WriteLine("woke up");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finally");
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("waiting for task to get inside the try clause...");
mre.WaitOne();
Console.WriteLine("Task entered try clause, exiting...");
Environment.Exit(0);
```

The output will be:

> starting task...
>
> waiting for task to get inside the try clause...
>
> sleeping...
>
> Task entered try clause, exiting...

And as you can see, no `finally`.